# How to show the inf can be achieved by some nonnegative $u\in H^1(M)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, entropy, ricci-flow

When I read some about Perelman's $\mathcal W$ function, I get stuck with the red line in the picture below.Seemly, I should to read the 8.2 Existence of minimizers of Evans' PDE. But I am not sure , so I ask this question.

Besides, I can find the 108 reference "Logarithmic Sobolev inequalities and the spectrum of Schrodinger operators". Where I can get it ? Or there are some paper which can replace it ?

Below picture is from the 208 of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]

Comment: The full text can be downloaded [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123681900501)

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks.